# Operator comma in C++ ?: conditional

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Could you tell me what's the problem with ?: operator it tells error:

```
 C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'int' to 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>'   
           c:\documents\visual studio 2005\projects\8.14\8.14\8.14.cpp  36
```

The Code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int B;
int A=(6,B=8);
bool c = true;
cout << endl << B;
while (B != 100)
{
cout << "qgkdf\n";
(A<B) ? (c = 100, B=100, cout << "!!!") : (A = 100);
A--;
}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the `,` is not a operator and the line `int A=(6,B=8);` is incorrect

Comment: @ABFORCE It is an operator.

Comment: @hvd: Can it be overload?

Comment: @ABFORCE: unfortunately, yes...

Comment: @ABFORCE [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Comment: @MatthieuM. : why unfortunately ?

Comment: @Synxis : Very thanks for your valuable link

Comment: The problem with the `?` operator is that people use it to write code like the above.

Answer (score 3):

The types of the 2 operands of the conditional operator needs to be the same.

```
(A<B) ? (c = 100, B=100, cout << "!!!") : (A = 100);
```

The type of `c = 100, B=100, cout << "!!!"` is the type of `cout << "!!!"`, which is `std::ostream`.

The type of of `A = 100` is `int`.

These 2 types do not match, hence the error.

EDIT: The comma operator returns the value of the last part. You cann add an int, for example:

```
(A<B) ? (c = 100, B=100, (cout << "!!!"), 42) : (A = 100);
//                                      ^^^^
```

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/rxcYMU).

Comment: @thomas This is also a solution. As the OP seems to want to obfuscate code, I don't which one he will prefer ;)

Comment: you can substitue with this code, work good : if (A<B) { c = 100; B=100; cout << "!!!"; } else { A = 100; } ;

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to write obfuscated code, make sure you know how to use casts, as the solution is obviously to cast the result of `cout << "!!!"` to an `int`:

```
(A<B) ? (c = 100, B=100, reinterpret_cast<int>(cout << "!!!")) : (A = 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the return value is not being used it might be clearer to cast both sides to void.
Although not as clear as just using a good old "if".

Answer (score 1):

This is blatant abuse of the ?: operator. Use an `if` statement. That's what they're for.